# Remove Section of a JSON File with json-simple (JAVA)

Tags: java

Hello I want to delete an section of a JSON File in Java with JSON-Simple.

The JSON File

```
{
        "MYID": {
            "user": "name",
            "task": "aufgabe",
            "status": "true"
        },
        "MYID2": {
            "user": "name2",
            "task": "aufgabe2",
            "status": "false"
        },
        "MYID3": {
            "user": "name3",
            "task": "aufgabe3",
            "status": "true"
        }
}
```

I want to delete the complete "MYID" section. I already tried `jsonObject.remove("MYID");` but it don't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jsonObj.getAsJsonObject("").remove("MYID");
```

This approach requires a String argument. First try to print the `jsonObject (jsonObect.toString())` or debug it. That should be a Map with another inner Maps and see the structure of such object to remove the part you are interested in.

Comment: Sorry i forgot that such method requeries an argument String. first tru to print the jsonObject (jsonObect.toString()) or debug it, that should be a MAP with another inner MAPS and see the structure of such object to remove the part of your interest

Answer (score 0):

I successfully removed element with this code:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

class SimpleJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JSONObject jObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(json);
        jObject.remove("MYID3");
        System.out.println(jObject);
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("/path/result2.json"))) {
            jObject.writeJSONString(writer);
        }

        // java 11 
        // Files.writeString(Path.of("/path/dir1", "result.json"), jObject.toJSONString());
    }
    ...
}
```

**Dependency:**
        
            com.googlecode.json-simple
            json-simple
            1.1.1

**Output**:

```
{
  "MYID": {
    "task": "aufgabe",
    "user": "name",
    "status": "true"
  },
  "MYID2": {
    "task": "aufgabe2",
    "user": "name2",
    "status": "false"
  }
}
```

Comment: do you know how to safe the file after the remove without creating new file

Comment: Have a look at updated answer. `Files.writeString(Path.of("/path/dir1", "result.json"), jObject.toJSONString());`

Comment: It is Java 11 example.

Comment: Updated for java 8